# Giving specific rights

Tags: permissions, chmod, groups

I have the directory called 'sales' and 2 groups called 'Sales' and 'HRM'.

As shown below, I have a list with all directories, and connected groups. Without changing the directory's group, i need to give 'HRM' group, reading access to the sales directory.

How do I do that?

```
localhost:/home/SMBmelvin # ls -l
total 0
drwxrwx--- 1 root   Administratie  0 May 11 13:39 administratie
drwxrwx--- 1 root   HRM            0 May 11 13:39 hrm
drwxrwx--- 1 root   ICT            0 May 11 13:39 ict
drwxrwx--- 1 root   Intranet       0 May 11 13:39 intranet
drwxrwx--- 1 root   Klantenservice 0 May 11 13:39 klantenservice
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root           0 May 11 13:34 Linux
drwxrwx--- 1 root   Marketing      0 May 11 13:39 marketing
drwxrwx--- 1 root   Sales          0 May 11 13:39 sales
drwxr-xr-x 1 Melvin root           0 May 11 13:34 Windows
```

I hope I can get a clear answer to this, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to do this without changing the group and without giving read access to others?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) [Edit] your question and copy&paste the `ls -l` output *as text*. Add all requested information or clarification to the question. ACLs might be a way to add permissions that don't fit the UNIX user/group/other permissions system.

Comment: @Bruni , yes that is correct. Without changing the group, I specifically need the HRM group to have reading access to anything within that directory aswell.

Answer (score 1):

A file can only belong to one group at a time. However, a user can be a member of multiple groups, and if a user is a member of a group that has permission to access a file, then the user can access that file as well.

The owner and group can be changed using the `chown` and `chgrp` commands.

```
chgrp HRM sales
```

would change the group of the directory sales to HRM

```
chmod g+r sales
```

would give read access to the group of directory sales.

```
chmod +r sales
```

would give read access to everybody. For more fine grained control you need to use Access Control Lists.